# Can I say this about the angle between a force vector and an inclined plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

[image]

Can I say that $\vec{F}$ makes angle $30^{\circ}$ with the inclined plane?

Comment: Are you talking about the angle between area vector of the inclined plane and the force vector?

Comment: Or just the angle with the inclined plane at which the force is applied?

Comment: @Thespaceguy No, the inclined plane is just an inclined plane. It isn't a vector. I just mean the angle with the inclined plane at which the force is applied.

Comment: No I am asking that whether you are trying to find the angle between the plane and the force or the area vector and the force vector?

Comment: And if you are talking just about the plane and the force ...no that's not 30° you have to  take the anticlockwise angle i.e 150°

Comment: @Thespaceguy isn't $30^{\circ}$ the anticlockwise angle?

Comment: No, it's the angle you are measuring from force vector to the plane downward. You have to measure from force to plane upward for anticlockwise angle!!

Comment: @Thespaceguy Do we always have to measure the angle from the force vector to the plane in the anticlockwise direction?

Comment: Yes always the anticlockwise angle is taken to be considered.

Comment: Without a full context this question is meaningless. You can consider either angle, depending on what are you actually doing and how are you doing it.

Comment: I am very confused now!!...@tryingtobeastoic please don't consider my answer as the correct one!!

Comment: Now it seems to me to be 30° to be the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always define a co-ordinate system (cartesian) to determine the force making an angle with the inclined otherwise you can consider so many ways to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It should be 150°.
As the angle you are taking is clockwise angle.
Anticlockwise angle should be taken.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Take a look at the picture, 150° is the anticlockwise angle whereas 30° is the clockwise angle!!

Comment: I edited the picture in my question. Could you please look into that?

Comment: Yes, but it's not the angle to be considered.

Comment: Who says that you have to move anticlockwise starting from the force and not from the plane? Unless you have the context of the situation, this is a meaningless questions. You can also draw the force with its tail touching the plane rather than the tip.